# Heroku and European Safe Harbor Compliance?

Tags: heroku

We are working with a client looking to launch in Europe and there are concerns if Heroku is compliant with Europe's Safe Harbor rules. I've done some Googling but most of the questions seem to be from 2011 without any clear answer.

Does anybody know if there is an update to this? Can we host a website for a European client on Heroku?